# "Cannot find Rhodes" creating a new Rhodes application in Eclipse

Tags: rhodes

I just started with Rhodes cross platform mobile application development. I followed the [rhostudio tutorial](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhostudio.tutorial) to install RhoStudio and to start creating a Rhodes application.

Once I click the **Finish** button in create new project wizard I get an error message:

> Cannot find Rhodes, need rhodes version equal or greater 3.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linked tutorial says:

> RhoStudio is an Eclipse plugin [...]

You'll need to install the actual development-platform, too. A tutorial on how to do this can be found [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/install).

---

You should also be sure to enter the path to your Rhodes-installation as illustrated [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhostudio.tutorial#edit-buildyml).

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I was missing a tiny yeh important part. I was not running gem script which comes along with RhoStudio setup. Now everything is fine. I even created sample app for IPhone using RhoStudio.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're opening Rhodes from the correct file.  On a Mac, the file to open is /Applications/Motorola RhoStudio/RhoStudio 64 bits (UNIX Executable File). The terminal prompt will ask you what version of Ruby you want to work with, and RhoStudio will open correctly once you answer.  I would assume that on the PC you'll want to open whatever link leads you to the same prompt:

Select Ruby version to start RhoStudio:
1) ruby-1.9.3-p194

On the other hand if I open macosx.cocoa.x86_64/RhoStudio.app, then everything seems fine at first but you get the "Cannot Find Rhodes" error when creating a new RhoMobile project.

Comment: That solved my problem - thank you.  (Although when I apps via bash scripts and the terminal window - there's always such a long pause before anything happens.  I find it faster to drag "RhoStudio 64 bits" into the terminal window and hit enter)

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

1) Uninstall rhode studio
2) Run "install gems" file
3) Reinstall rhodestudio
4) Create your project